# fixed top my cross button of form

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, css-position, fixed

how can i fixed top my cross button ?
help me please !

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid user-information" id="registerid">
                    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-blue-cross fixed " type="submit" style="float:right">X</button>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-4"></div>
                        <div class="animatable bounceIn">
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <form class="form-horizontal error" novalidate="">
                                    <div class="control-group error">
                                        <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
                                            <span class="input-group-addon" id="sizing-addon1"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" aria-hidden="true"></span></span>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName" name="firstName" placeholder="Name" required="" minlength="3">
                                        </div>
                                        <p class="help-block"></p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="control-group error">
                                        <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
                                            <span class="input-group-addon" id="sizing-addon1"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></span></span>
                                            <input id="email" type="email" required="" name="email" aria-invalid="true" class="form-control" placeholder="...@gmail.com">
                                        </div>
                                        <p class="help-block"></p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="control-group error">
                                        <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
                                            <span class="input-group-addon" id="sizing-addon1"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock" aria-hidden="true"></span></span>
                                            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required="" minlength="8">
                                        </div>
                                        <p class="help-block"></p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class=" control-group error">
                                        <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
                                            <span class="input-group-addon" id="sizing-addon1"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-link" aria-hidden="true"></span></span>
                                            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="confirm_password" name="confirm_password" placeholder="Confirm Password" data-validation-matches-message="Must match confirm password entered above" data-validation-matches-match="password" required="">
                                        </div>
                                        <p class="help-block"></p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="control-group">
                                        <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
                                            <span class="input-group-addon" id="sizing-addon1"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone" aria-hidden="true"></span></span>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="mobile" name="mobile" placeholder="Mobile Number" required="" minlength="11">
                                        </div>
                                        <p class="help-block"></p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="control-group">
                                        <button class="btn btn-success btn-block" type="submit" style="float:right">Submit</button>
                                        <div class="input-group">
                                            <input id="terms-and-conditions" type="checkbox" data-validation-required-message="You must agree to the terms and conditions" required="" name="terms-and-conditions" aria-invalid="true"> I agree to the <a href="#">terms and conditions</a>
                                            <p class="help-block" style="display:none;"></p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </form>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

see , my cross button is not fix .  how can i fix my cross button .
i know only navbar can be fixed .

```
.btn-blue-cross{
    position:fixed;
}
```

it will working but when i am doing my screen small like as mobile version , then button will hide . 
how can i solve this problem ?

Comment: what do you mean fix? Does it mean that you want it to stick on top when scrolling just like nav-bar??

Comment: yes . like as nav-bar  (example : navbar-fixed-top)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
.btn-blue-cross{
    position:fixed;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this following code in `css` button which you want to be fixed on top on scroll.

```
.btn-blue-cross{ 
position: fixed; 
top: 10px; 
right: 10px; 
}
```

Let me know if it works and if thats what you wanted

Answer (score 1):

css will be:

```
.btn-blue-cross{
    position:fixed;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want your button to remain visible change your HTML structure to account for it by placing it in a column and then using an offset for the form. Change the btn from fixed to absolute in your css if you dont want it to scroll with the page.

See working Snippet.

```css
.btn-blue-cross {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid user-information" id="registerid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-1">
      <button class="btn btn-lg btn-blue-cross fixed " type="submit" style="float:right">X</button>
    </div>
    <div class="animatable bounceIn">
      <div class="col-xs-10 col-md-4 col-md-offset-3">
        <form class="form-horizontal error" novalidate="">
          <div class="control-group error">
            <div class="input-group input-group-lg"> <span class="input-group-addon" id="sizing-addon1"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" aria-hidden="true"></span></span>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName" name="firstName" placeholder="Name" required="" minlength="3">
            </div>
            <p class="help-block"></p>
          </div>
          <div class="control-group error">
            <div class="input-group input-group-lg"> <span class="input-group-addon" id="sizing-addon1"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></span></span>
              <input id="email" type="email" required="" name="email" aria-invalid="true" class="form-control" placeholder="...@gmail.com">
            </div>
            <p class="help-block"></p>
          </div>
          <div class="control-group error">
            <div class="input-group input-group-lg"> <span class="input-group-addon" id="sizing-addon1"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock" aria-hidden="true"></span></span>
              <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required="" minlength="8">
            </div>
            <p class="help-block"></p>
          </div>
          <div class=" control-group error">
            <div class="input-group input-group-lg"> <span class="input-group-addon" id="sizing-addon1"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-link" aria-hidden="true"></span></span>
              <input type="password" class="form-control" id="confirm_password" name="confirm_password" placeholder="Confirm Password" data-validation-matches-message="Must match confirm password entered above" data-validation-matches-match="password" required="">
            </div>
            <p class="help-block"></p>
          </div>
          <div class="control-group">
            <div class="input-group input-group-lg"> <span class="input-group-addon" id="sizing-addon1"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone" aria-hidden="true"></span></span>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="mobile" name="mobile" placeholder="Mobile Number" required="" minlength="11">
            </div>
            <p class="help-block"></p>
          </div>
          <div class="control-group">
            <button class="btn btn-success btn-block" type="submit" style="float:right">Submit</button>
            <div class="input-group">
              <input id="terms-and-conditions" type="checkbox" data-validation-required-message="You must agree to the terms and conditions" required="" name="terms-and-conditions" aria-invalid="true">I agree to the <a href="#">terms and conditions</a>

              <p class="help-block" style="display:none;"></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```